# Excel: How to display a value in million or any custom type

Tags: excel, excel-formula, number-formatting

I would like to display a cell value having number in million or any other custom form. For example, if I have a value stored as 5,000,000 , this will display as 5M symbolically. Or, for some other form say I define a symbol T as 1,000 so, a value of 5,000,000 will display as 5,000T but store as 5000000.

Comment: You basically add a comma to the end of the number format for each thousand you want to divide the displayed number by. So `"0,,\M"` would display millions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom number format (ctrl+1) with this type:

```
#,##0,\T
```

[image]